# filter pandas datetime by last row's date

Tags: pandas

I want to filter the dataframe to keep only the date match the last row's date. so only the same date as the last row's date will be kept.

e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

data = [
    "2014-03-15 12:00:00.000",
    "2014-03-15 12:10:00.000",
    "2014-03-18 13:00:00.000",
    "2014-03-18 13:10:00.000",
    "2014-03-18 14:10:00.000",
    "2014-03-18 15:20:00.000"
    ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['ts'])
df['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ts'],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
print(df)

d = datetime.datetime.strptime("2014-03-18 01:00:00.000", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
df1 = df[df['ts'] > d]
print(df1)
```

Current code use a hardcode date `d` to filter it out. how can I make it more smarter to pickup the last row's date as my filter?

Expected output:

```
                   ts
2 2014-03-18 13:00:00
3 2014-03-18 13:10:00
4 2014-03-18 14:10:00
5 2014-03-18 15:20:00
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
s = df['ts'].dt.date # s will contain only the dates (with no time)

df[s.eq(s.iloc[-1])] # compare dates with the last one
```

Output:

```
                   ts
2 2014-03-18 13:00:00
3 2014-03-18 13:10:00
4 2014-03-18 14:10:00
5 2014-03-18 15:20:00
```